# Cannot find Authentication_pam.so in any pam library packages

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu-12.04, percona, pam

My aim is to MySQL authentication using operating system users.I have installed the 'libpam_mysql' packages as well as libnss packages in my ubuntu server.My Mysql database is also running in the same machine.I need to create pam proxy users to map the linux users to my mysql groups.In one of the forum i find that authentication_pam.so file is required for the which i coudn't find in any linux packages.Please help me so that i can do the processes as mentioned in the page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html.

Thanks and regards,
Abhijith